# compare an object with null

Tags: javascript, object-comparison

when we need to compare two objects `a` and `b` we also should test that one of them is not `null`.

However, knowing that is a total chaos

```
{}    - null   => -0
[]    - null   => 0
1     - null   => 1
"1"   - null   => 1
true  - null   => 1
false - null   => 0
"a"   - null   => NaN
null  - null   => 0

"a" == null    false
"a"  > null    false
"a"  < null    false
```

```js
let arr = [
  { name: "a" },
  { name: null },
  null,
  { name: "zaa" },
  { name: "dgh" }
];
let sortByName = function (a, b) {
  if (a == null || b == null) return a - b;
  if (a.name == null || b.name == null) return a.name - b.name;
  return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
};

console.log(arr.sort(sortByName));
```

the result is the following:

```
0: {name: 'a'}
1: {name: null}
2: null
3: {name: 'dgh'}
4: {name: 'zaa'}
```

how would you explain such a result?

Comment: `a-b` when either a or b is null doesn't make sense since it results in NaN and not 1, 0, or -1.

Comment: Same with the name, if `a.name == null || b.name == null`

Comment: "*how would you explain such a result?*" with the fact that returning `NaN` is not at all the expected result of a comparison function? How is this at all related to `null` when it's comparison expecting numbers and you're feeding it `NaN`s by subtracting non-numbers?

Comment: You are returning `NaN`s here. My guess is that they are treated like 0, so the sorting function thinks `"a"` and the two null variants are to be considered equal.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it make sens, cause you need however to do something when comparing

Comment: @CherryDT "*My guess is that they are treated like 0*" they aren't handled in any way consistently.

Comment: @serge "*cause you need however to do something when comparing*" yes, you need to **compare** the two values and provide indication whether one is greater, lesser, or equal to the other. Subtraction *only works with numbers* (or anything that converts to a number cleanly, like Date). It's not at all how you compare objects, strings, or a lot of other things.

Answer (score 2):

```
null - {} === NaN
{} - null === -0
```

Here:

```
if (a == null || b == null) return a - b;
```

You are subtracting *anything* from `null` or `null` from *anything*, if one of the 2 values is `null`.

Replace `null` with an empty string and use that in your comparison:

```js
let arr = [
  { name: "a" },
  { name: null },
  null,
  { name: "zaa" },
  { name: "dgh" }
];
let sortByName = function (a, b) {
  return (a?.name ?? '').localeCompare(b?.name ?? '');
};

console.log(arr.sort(sortByName));
```

Comment: Even then the result would be the same, it probably makes more sense to treat null as an empty string. Then the nulls won't mix with other things and everything can be simplified to `(a?.name ?? '').localeCompare(b?.name ?? '')`

Comment: NOK: "0" means equality

Comment: I would say shoud be ` '' > null`

Comment: Then you can extend the filter function to handle that, @serge. Don't go changing the question on me, mate.

Comment: For example append `|| (a?.name != null) - (b?.name != null)` (these conditions when coerced to a number will become 0 or 1, so subtraction does work here)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it so that `null` comes before `{name: null}` you can extend @Cerbrus answer to handle this.

A simple way to do this is convert both terms `a` and `b` into values that will in the end sort the way you like.  I find the easiest way is to just prefix the input terms with another character you want to sort on.

eg.

```
   If term is null, just return `0`;
   If term is `{name:null}` return `1`;
   Everything else just return `3` + term;
```

It's kind of like creating a compound index..

Doing the above you can see it's very easy to make the sort do whatever you want based on certain conditions..  Eg, if you wanted `null` to go to the end like `undefined` simply change it's prefix, eg. make it `4`

eg.

```js
let arr = [
  { name: "a" },
  { name: null },
  null,
  { name: "zaa" },
  { name: "dgh" }
];

function toStr(a) {
  if (a === null) return '0';
  else if (a.name === null) return '1';
  else return '3' + a.name;
}

let sortByName = function (a, b) {
  return toStr(a).localeCompare(toStr(b));
};

console.log(arr.sort(sortByName));
```